# Visual Studio 2012 'NaN' is not a valid value property for 'FontSize' with SharePoint packages

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012

I don't know what I changed to my Visual Studio (Maybe some extension, maybe some setting?) - but I can't use any "SharePoint" stuff anymore. When clicking on a feature or on a package (something which will open a special wizard) I get the following Exception:

[image]

I have tried installing Visual Studio 2012 CU3, re-installing the SHarePoint developer tools, uninstalling all extensions - the error stays.
I'm close to just uninstalling Visual Studio and reinstalling it, I would like to know how to solve the error another way or to know where the error came from. I surely did not change anything relating to the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.SHarePoint.Designers.Models.Packages" dll.

Any tips short of uninstall - reinstall? I'm not sure that will work either as I re-installed the SharePoint tools already and the CU3, which should refresh a lot of files anyways.

Sidenote: I did reinstall Visual Studio - same error. Reinstall SharePoint?

Comment: It does this with a new/blank Sharepoint project loaded (not a pre-existing project)?

Comment: Exactly. Fresh project, empty template. Also with old projects. I uninstalled all extensions (besides standard MS stuff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no help here.

`devenv.exe /resetsettings` seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Bless you, sir! +1 to working for me too.